# Iterate over children within a snapshot and get values within each child in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the data below in my Firebase Real-Time DB:
[image]

I am trying to iterate to get all children of the "00001" id and then get the value of "timeDetected" for each of the children. Right now I have the swift code:

```
for item in snapshot.children {

    print(item)

}
```

This outputs each child to the console as seen below:

```
Snap (fouihbnfqwubfwqouyb) {
    timeDetected = "2018-05-28T16:00:13Z";
}
Snap (fouihbnfqwubtgowqouyb) {
    timeDetected = "2018-05-28T16:00:18Z";
}
Snap (fouohbnfqwubtgowqouyb) {
    timeDetected = "2018-05-28T16:00:43Z";
}
```

How can I go about only printing out the value of "timeDetected" instead of the entire snapshot so that my console looks like this:

```
timeDetected = "2018-05-28T16:00:13Z";
timeDetected = "2018-05-28T16:00:18Z";
timeDetected = "2018-05-28T16:00:43Z";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this simple issue for a while and have not been able to make much headway.

Comment: Curious why you aren't using Firestore instead of RTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are reading the parent node with observeSingleEvent(of: .value so this function reads the data, maintains order, unwraps each child node safely and prints the time. I cast the value to an String but you could use double or something else. I suggest using a double to store your timestamps.

```
func readTimes() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("00001")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allChildren = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for snap in allChildren {
            if let time = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeDetected").value as? String {
                print("timeDetected = \(time)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
timeDetected = 2018-05-28T16:00:13Z
timeDetected = 2018-05-28T16:00:18Z
timeDetected = 2018-05-28T16:00:43Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in snapshot.children {
    if let itemSnapshot = item as? Snapshot {
        for timeDetected in itemSnapshot.children {
            print(timeDetected)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Close but there is no Snapshot in Firebase - DataSnapshot is what you want there. Also, that doesn't print the times. It prints the child node like this *Snap (timeDetected) 2018-05-28T16:00:13Z* and I believe the OP wanted the VALUE of each child node.